# download html file client side with object with variables

Tags: javascript, download, console.log

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server), I've been able to create an export button that download file on client side.
Now I'm trying to create an html page instead of a plain text file, and I encounter a lot of issues when I try to insert variables into it.
This is my code :

```html
<a href="#" id="export-button" onclick="exports()">export</a>
<script src="example.js"></script>
```

```js
function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
}

function exports() {
    let test_int = 10
    let test_str = 'hello world'
    let test_array = { "test": 10 }
    content = `<script>console.log(${test_array})</script>`
    download('export.html', content)
}
```

This is my error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Object'` But I don't have the error when I try to log some `int`
Anyway I hope my problem is understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a Data URI, you also have to change the file's type. If you just have a text file for your HTML, then you will just view the HTML as a text file. Also, if you want to print out an object then you have to stringify it to be readable.

```
function download(filename, text, file_type){
    file_type = file_type || 'TXT';
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    if(file_type == "HTML"){
        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    }else{
        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    }
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
}

function exports() {
    let test_int = 10
    let test_str = 'hello world'
    let test_array = { "test": 10 }
    content = `<script>console.log(${JSON.stringify(test_array)})</script>`
    download('export.html', content, 'HTML')
}
```